# MySQL Database last inserted row in all tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have staging database and needs to find last inserted row in all database tables, some tables also dont have timestamp column or Ids in orderwise. if there is any way please...

Comment: you should provide your table structure as well as a bit elaboration of your quesiton

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
SELECT 
COLUMN_NAME,
ORDINAL_POSITION
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
AND TABLE_NAME ='YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

[Information_schema.columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) stores column specific information

Answer (score 0):

You can get all table and its last inserted id

```
SELECT 
TABLE_NAME,
max(ORDINAL_POSITION) last_inserted_id
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DB_NAME'
GROUP BY
TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Hmm, for me, this does not display the last inserted ID, but it looks random. Can you explain the query further?